# Magento : Bigger Text Input For Module Configuration

Tags: magento, configuration, admin, magento-1.9

I'm creating a custom module for Magento 1.9. I need to have much bigger text input field in configuration. The normal field has one line high, I need to be multiple lines high.

Is there a default input type that I'm missing?

Do I need to create a custom input field?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In magento custom extension configuration, you can add textarea using this code.

```
<yourfieldid translate="label comment">
   <label>Title</label>
   <frontend_type>textarea</frontend_type>
   <sort_order>70</sort_order>
   <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
   <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
   <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
</yourfieldid>
```

Comment: That did the job! Thanks!